# Automatic formatting of amount field textbox(Decimal value ) with coma for every 3 digits, when user tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, formatting

Could someone please help me with the code for below requirement or scenarios...I achieved 80 %, but stuck up with autoformatting...Its silly but new for me :(

Well my business user would like to feature for a big amount field textbox which should allow 2 decimal points only.i.e when she types 1000, it should be automatically formatted as "1,000.00" and when she types 1000000, it should be like "1,000,000.00" and when she types 1K, it should be formatted as automatically "1,000.00" and when she types 10000.23 it should be "10,000.23" and M/m should be million and b/B should be billion. Well I could achieve all these M/M, k/K etc and limitting the decimal only to 2 decimal points. Even I kept validation and all like it wont allow any characters except k/K,m/M,b/B,"." and ",". Please also remember, if user mentions just 2k, it should be "2,000.00" i.e I mean to say, if no values she keyin for decimal or no "." in the number value in textbox, it should be that "number.00" against to 23333.32 which should appear as "23,333.32"

But I have a problem of implementing autoformatting the inputs with a coma for interval of every 3 digits starting from first digit to the left of decimal place. I am not sure how to do this autoformatting for coma... This should happen only when the user finishes keying in the input and presses tab. Please help me achieve this :( I would be really greatful if you can share the sample code for me like above. (*Please consider all scenarios I mentioned while we try for code for this*) :) Meanwhile I will also workout ways to achieve this...I know it might look silly to you, but new for me  :(....thank you all....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 12345.67); // 12,345.67
String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 12345.6); // 12,345.60
String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 12345); // 12,345.00

String.Format("{0:0,0.##}", 12345.67); // 12,345.67
String.Format("{0:0,0.##}", 12345.6); // 12,345.6
String.Format("{0:0,0.##}", 12345); // 12,345
```

When the text box loses focus:

```
double value;

if (double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out value))
{
    txtBox.Text = String.Format("...", value);
}
else
{
    // Some code to handle the bad input (not parsable to double)
}
```

Comment: Hi Yorye - First of all thank you much for your response, I too remember doing something like this sometimeback. Unfortunately I am not achieving what I wanted. The above code just displays me " ..." in the textbox and in some other cases, just the same number what I typed is being shown. i.e if I type 22, its showing only 22. Else "..." and not the value as expected like above.

Comment: Please help me...I am not sure if I am going somewhere wrong too :( sorry for the trouble....

Comment: That is probably because you left the "..." at the format line. If I understand what you want, then use this in the if section: txtBox.Text = String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", value);

Comment: Hi Yorye Thats Perfect thank you so much :) It came out perfectly. But one problem is, when I just type and tab, it all goes very good as per my validation and your solution too for formatting. But when I tab bac to this textbox, the value is highlighted and I am unable to overwrite on that to update any new value :( Which my business user wants.....I wrote a keydown event to do validations which checks if there  is 2 digits after decimal place, it will not allow the user to type any number further i.e I set e.handled true. Please help me to overwrite in this scenario :( Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Yorye thank you so much, I have found solution myself :) I used txtbox.HideSelection and based on that bool condition I am enabling or disabling e.Handled. It works as expected. Pretty good. But last one very silly question - When I type just 2, it displays 02.00. I thought it would be good if I can display just 2.00 instead of 02.00 basically a leading zero in case of single digit :)

Comment: I found a big issue on testing my code below. i.e only any one of the following is being satisfied at a time and not both :( I want both of them to be satisfied. 1) The user shouldn't be able to keyin any 3rd digit after 2 digits after decimal point and 2) When the user tabs back from the next control back to this textbox value where I am implementing these validations, it is highlighting the text, but doesn't allows the user to overwrite :(..... I want both of these things to be achieved and could someone please help me with the correct code or correct my code please....

Comment: private void txtAmount_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string textValue = txtAmount.Text.Trim();
            if (txtAmount.HideSelection )
            {
                if (textValue.IndexOf(".") > 0)
                {
                    string[] decimalvalue = textValue.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                    if (decimalvalue[1].Length >= 2)
                        cancelCharacter = true;
                    else
                        cancelCharacter = false;
                }else
                {cancelCharacter = false;
                }}

Comment: It has nothing to do with the formatting issue. Post it as a different question. (and accepting the answer will be appreciated, if it helped you)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, your solution helped me a lot. But wondering how I can resolve my current issue, I will post it as a different post as guided by you, thanks mate and I really appreciate it :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 function decimalformat(amount) {
        var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
        var a = amount.split('.', 2)
        var d = a[1];
        var i = parseInt(a[0]);
        if (isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
        var minus = '';
        if (i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
        i = Math.abs(i);
        var n = new String(i);
        var a = [];
        while (n.length > 3) {
            var nn = n.substr(n.length - 3);
            a.unshift(nn);
            n = n.substr(0, n.length - 3);
        }
        if (n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
        n = a.join(delimiter);
        if (d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
        else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
        amount = minus + amount;
        return amount;
    }
```

please try this onblur of your textbox

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of the code in your answer to make it easier to read? Also, can you make it clear what the solution is? Thanks